# HTML5/JavaScript/PhoneGap onclick does not function as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite, cordova

was following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/edwardtoday/2204864) on how to use SQLite with PhoneGap/Cordova. I copy pasted the code and fixed the spacing, however, after spending a lot of time trying to make it work, I'm still stumped.

At first I thought that the sql statements had an error or two that's why I'm not getting any results. However, upon further checking, even simple alert statements were not being executed when the `onclick` methods of certain buttons were pressed. The `onload` method of the Body was not being executed as well.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" name="viewport" content="width=default-width; user-scalable=no" />

    <title>Embedded Sql Example</title>

    <!-- include the next line to use phonegap javascript functions -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap.js"></script>

    <!-- include the next line to use jquery functions in your application
    you must download this and include the directory your html file is in
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- main scripts used in this example -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/gitScript.js"></script>


</head>

<body onload="onBodyLoad();">
    <h1>WebSQL</h1>
    <input id="txFirstName" type="text" placeholder="FirstName">
    <input id="txLastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">

    <input type="button" value="Add record" onclick="AddValueToDB();">
    <input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="ListDBValues();"> 

    <br><br>

    <span style="font-weight:bold;">Currently stored values:</span>
    <span id="lbUsers"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a folder named `js` containing all the JavaScript files I used. Here is the gitScript.js file:

```
// global variables
var db;
var shortName = "WebSqlDB";
var version = "1.0";
var displayName = "WebSqlDB";
var maxSize = 65535;

// this is called when an error happens in a transaction
function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.message + " code: " + error.code);
}

// this is called when a successful transaction happens
function successCallBack() {
   alert("DEBUGGING: success");
}

function nullHandler(){};

// called when the application loads
function onBodyLoad(){

    // This alert is used to make sure the application is loaded correctly
    // you can comment this out once you have the application working
    alert("DEBUGGING: we are in the onBodyLoad() function");

    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        // not all mobile devices support databases  if it does not, the
        // following alert will display
        // indicating the device will not be albe to run this application
        alert("Databases are not supported in this browser.");
        return;
    }

    // this line tries to open the database base locally on the device
    // if it does not exist, it will create it and return a database
    // object stored in variable db
    db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);

    // this line will try to create the table User in the database just created/openned
    db.transaction(function(tx){

        tx.executeSql( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FirstName TEXT NOT NULL, LastName TEXT NOT NULL)", [],nullHandler,errorHandler);
    },errorHandler,successCallBack);

}

// list the values in the database to the screen using jquery to
// update the #lbUsers element
function ListDBValues() {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert("Databases are not supported in this browser.");
        return;
    }

    // this line clears out any content in the #lbUsers element on the
    // page so that the next few lines will show updated
    // content and not just keep repeating lines
    $('#lbUsers').html('');

    // this next section will select all the content from the User table
    // and then go through it row by row
    // appending the UserId  FirstName  LastName to the  #lbUsers element
    // on the page
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM User;", [],
            function(transaction, result) {
                if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = result.rows.item(i);
                        $('#lbUsers').append('<br>' + row.UserId + '. ' + row.FirstName+ ' ' + row.LastName);
                    }
                }
            },errorHandler);
    },errorHandler,nullHandler);

    return;

}

// this is the function that puts values into the database using the
// values from the text boxes on the screen
function AddValueToDB() {

    alert("Add Value to DB entered");
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert("Databases are not supported in this browser.");
        return;
    }

    // this is the section that actually inserts the values into the User table
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName)
            VALUES (?,?)',[$('#txFirstName').val(), $('#txLastName').val()],
            nullHandler,errorHandler);
    });

    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName)
            VALUES (?,?)',["FirstName", "LastName"],
            nullHandler,errorHandler);
    });


    // this calls the function that will show what is in the User table in the database
    ListDBValues();

    return false; 
}
```

I don't really know what's wrong with it. I've inspected it closely with [another SQLite PhoneGap tutorial](http://phonegaptutorial.blogspot.com/2012/12/phonegap-how-to-create-databasestore.html) and I'm having a hard time seeing where the code above went wrong.

I have a feeling I'm missing something basic, it's been a long time since I had to work with JavaScript and my first time working with HTML5.

Comment: The thing that cut my eyes is your phonegap.js include.  these days its better to use this <script src="cordova.js></script>  ... phonegap will automaticly include your cordova framework. Its also not called phonegap.js anymore.  Try to replace that.

Comment: If this is the case, then ofc nothing will work that you are trying to do.  Without the cordova.js framework included to your app, you cant do anything at all.  Error messages is not displayed on your phone, so you kinda need to "brain debug" your code for cordova in most ocations.  I dont know if you are using eclipse or something else.  I am using phonegap build always.

Comment: Let me know i will look again later today, and if so it was what i suggested i will make an answer for you aswell.

Comment: Then why is it that for the second tutorial I linked, `phonegap.js` works? Also, I've added `cordova.js` (I took it from here https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/trunk/com.mds.apg/resources/phonegap/1.9.0/cordova-1.9.0.js?r=172) in my js folder and pointed to that instead and it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are errors in the JavaScript file. I figured this out by linking another JavaScript file and the html file can see the functions in the second JavaScript file just fine. I used the Chrome Debugger to find out where the errors were and those errors are for a different question altogether.

Also, it seems that there's no difference between using phonegap.js and cordova.js.